# validate numbers displayed in range in angular

Tags: angular

I currently displaying Min and Max fields which would be a range values in my angular 4 application. I need to apply validation to ensure that the range is sequential and they don't overlap. For e.g

If the ranges are like below then the second row cannot start from anything below 20M and it has to start from 20M.

```
10M - 20M
20M - 40M
40M - 60M
```

I have applied the required field validation but not sure how to handle this validation. Please see my implementation below

```
 </tr>
            <tr *ngFor="let item of domicileInfo.taxAssesment.items; let last = last;">
            <td *ngIf="!last">
                <click-input contenteditable="true">
                    <input [(ngModel)]="item.minSize"  required min="0" max="999999999999999" numberFormat="shortNumberFormat:.0">
                </click-input>
              </td>

              <td *ngIf="!last">
                  <click-input contenteditable="true">
                      <input [(ngModel)]="item.maxSize" required min="0" max="999999999999999" numberFormat="shortNumberFormat:.0">
                  </click-input>
              </td>  
             <td  colspan="2" *ngIf="last"  class="text-right">  <span>&gt;</span>
                  <click-input contenteditable="true">
                      <input [(ngModel)]="item.minSize" required min="0" max="999999999999999" numberFormat="shortNumberFormat:.0">
                  </click-input>
              </td>     
              <td class="text-right">
                <click-input [classNames]="['percentage']" contenteditable="true">
                    <input [(ngModel)]="item.values[0]"  numberFormat="numberPercent:.0-2" required min="0" max="999999999999999">
                </click-input>
              </td>
              <td class="text-right">
                  <click-input [classNames]="['percentage']" contenteditable="true">
                      <input [(ngModel)]="item.values[1]"  numberFormat="numberPercent:.0-2" required min="0" max="999999999999999">
                  </click-input>
              </td>
            </tr>
```

Component code

```
import { Component,OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { BsModalRef } from 'ngx-bootstrap';
import { Base } from '@wtw/toolkit';
import * as BackendDto from '../../../../api/dtos';
import * as BackendProxy from '../../../../api/proxies';
import { IModalConfirmation } from '@wtw/platform/interfaces';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import * as Rx from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { RunService } from '@wtw/platform/services';
import { CONSTS } from '../../../../config';

const minCapRequirement = 'minCapReq';
const premuimTaxCap = 'premTaxCap';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-domicile-selection',
  templateUrl: './domicile-selection.component.html'
})
export class DomicileSelectionComponent extends Base.ReactiveComponent implements OnInit, IModalConfirmation {
  domicileInfo: BackendDto.DomicileInformation;
  domicileOldInfo: BackendDto.DomicileInformation;
  public data: any;
  public onClose: Rx.Subject<boolean>;
  public active = false;
  public currentSelectedCurrency = '';
  public domicileId: number;
  public domiciles: BackendDto.Domicile[];
  public amendAssumptions: string;
  differ: any;
  fieldCategories: typeof BackendDto.DynamicFieldCategory = BackendDto.DynamicFieldCategory;

  private domicile: BackendDto.Domicile;
  private _selectedIndustries: BackendDto.Industry[];
  oldValue:string;
  constructor(
    private _bsModalRef: BsModalRef,
    private _refProxy: BackendProxy.ReferenceProxy,
    private _runs: RunService,
    private _translate: TranslateService

  ) {

    super();

  }

  public ngOnInit() {
    this.onClose = new Rx.Subject();
    return [this._runs.activeRun.subscribe(r => {
        this.currentSelectedCurrency = r.currencyInfo.currentSelectedCurrency;
    })];
  }


  public show() {
    this.domicileId = this.data.domicile.id;
    this.domicile = this.data.domicile;
    this.domiciles = this.data.domiciles;
    this._selectedIndustries = this.data.selectedIndustries;
    this.domicileInfo = this.domicile.domicileInformation;
    this.amendAssumptions = this._translate.instant('CAPTIVES.DOMICILES.AMENDASSUMPTIONS', { domicile:  this.domicile.name });
    this.active = true;

  }

  public close() {
    this.hide(null);
  }

  public udpatevalue(item,value) {
    item.maxSize = value;
  }
  public ok() {
    this.data.domicileId = this.domicileId;
    this.data.domicileInfo = this.domicileInfo;
    this.hide(true);
  }

  public cancel() {
    this.hide(false);
  }

  domicileChanged($event) {
    if (this.domicileId === this.domicile.id) {
      this.domicileInfo = this.domicile.domicileInformation;
    } else {
      this._loadInformation();
    }
  }

  private _loadInformation() {
    this._refProxy.getDefaultDomicileInformationForClient(this.domicileId, this._selectedIndustries[0].id)
      .uiSignal('infos')
      .subscribe(ret => {
        this.domicileInfo = ret.data;
        this.domicileOldInfo = this.domicileInfo;
        const domicileName = this.domiciles.find(x => x.id === this.domicileId).name;

        this.amendAssumptions = this._translate.instant('CAPTIVES.DOMICILES.AMENDASSUMPTIONS', { domicile: domicileName });
      });
  }


  private hide(nextVal?: boolean) {
    this.active = false;
    this.onClose.next(nextVal);
    this._bsModalRef.hide();
  }

  get addnDomicileDetailMinCapReq(): BackendDto.DomicileAddnDetail {
    return this.domicileInfo.addnDomcileDetails.find(x => x.fieldInfo.key === minCapRequirement);
  }

  get addnDomicileDetailPremuimTaxCap(): BackendDto.DomicileAddnDetail {
    return this.domicileInfo.addnDomcileDetails.find(x => x.fieldInfo.key === premuimTaxCap);
  }

  get maxCurrency() {
    return CONSTS.general.maximumCurrencyValue;
  }
}
```

UI

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`[min`] and `[max]` validator directives have been removed in Angular 4. See the GitHub discussion [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/17491#issuecomment-308900276).

For now you have to implement the directives yourself.

```
import { Directive, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Validator, NG_VALIDATORS, AbstractControl, Validators, ValidationErrors } from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({
  selector: '[min]',
  providers: [{ provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting: MinValidatorDirective, multi: true }]
})
export class MinValidatorDirective implements Validator {
  @Input() min: number;

  validate(control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null {
    const validation = Validators.min(+this.min)(control);

    return validation && validation.min ? { min: true } : null;
  }
}
```

[Live demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pstbvq)

Comment: Sorry i wasnt referring to min and max validation. I was referring to range validation. How do I validate the ranges. If the user sets the range of the first row to say 10,000 to 20,000 then the subsequent row has to start at 10,000 and cant be number greater than or less than that number. I may have to anyways remove the min and max as they are going to be set by the user and hence cant hardcode it

Comment: The directive that you shared validates against a hardcoded value in the html control. In my case the validation is done based on the user input.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the issue by writing the following logic in my component and html. As you can see below, i am handing the min and max value as the user enters value in the input control

component

```
isMinValid(currentItem: any, item_IDX: number) {
    if (item_IDX === 0) {
      return true;
    }

    var previousItem = this.domicileInfo.taxAssesment.items[item_IDX - 1];
    if (currentItem.minSize != previousItem.maxSize) {
      return false;

    }
    return true;
  }




    isMaxValid(currentItem: any, item_IDX: number) {
        if (item_IDX === 0) {
          return true;
        }

        var previousItem = this.domicileInfo.taxAssesment.items[item_IDX - 1];
        if (currentItem.maxSize <= currentItem.minSize) {
          return false;
        }
        return true;
      }
```

html

```
<td *ngIf="!last" >
            <click-input   [classNames]="{'has-warning': !isMinValid(item,item_IDX) }">
                <!-- <input [(ngModel)]="item.minSize"  (ngModelChange)="modelChanged(item,item_IDX)" required min="0" max="999999999999999" numberFormat="shortNumberFormat:.0"> -->
                 <input [(ngModel)]="item.minSize"   required min="0" max="999999999999999" numberFormat="shortNumberFormat:.0"> 
            </click-input>
          </td>

          <td *ngIf="!last">
              <click-input  [classNames]="{'has-warning': !isMaxValid(item,item_IDX) }">
                  <!-- <input [(ngModel)]="item.maxSize"  (ngModelChange)="modelChanged(item,item_IDX)" required min="0" max="999999999999999" numberFormat="shortNumberFormat:.0"> -->
                   <input [(ngModel)]="item.maxSize"   required min="0" max="999999999999999" numberFormat="shortNumberFormat:.0"> 
              </click-input>
          </td>
```